# Creating a notification system using a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am creating a firefox extension that should give a notification when the user hits specific sites. I do not want the same kind of notification that firefox gives for pop-ups. I don't want the user to have to go through the hassle of clicking the X in order to close the notification. Instead, I would like it to look like what happens when a normal firefox download is completed - a notification comes up, and automatically goes after a few seconds. On a mac, it looks like a growl notification, and I love the way it looks. Is there an easy way to implement this feature?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify Mike's statement, to accept answer (which you should always do if the answer was helpful) you click on a checkbox next to it so the checkbox turns green. Also, now that you have >15 reputation, you have enough rep to up-vote any answers you find useful/good - see the "faq" look at the top of StackOverflow page for amounts of reputation needed to do various things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to implement "Download Complete" type one - but since entire FF AFAIK is implemented in XUL, probably it's doable.

I have [found the following](http://userlogos.org/book/export/html/4101):

> chrome://global/content/alerts/alert.xul F Window used for stuff like "download complete" that shows in lower right

Haowever, if you don't find a way to do that, why not implement banner-notifications, the way StackOverflow does? They are not obtrusive as far as site functionality, don't require extra work to get rid of (well, SO ones do but you can rig yours to automatically fade away after a time), and very visible/noticeable with the right styling.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [this type of notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications#Pop-ups).